# SQL Product Categories with Product Count and Parent-Categories

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write a SQL query to fetch:

```
Category_ID, Category_Name, Category_Parent, Category, ProductCount 
from two tables Product_Category and Product
```

[Product_Category has columns: id, name, parent_id, status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxD1r.png)

[Product has columns: id, category_id, name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKGcn.png)

I want to get the result from the query:

```
Category_ID | Category_Name | Category_Parent | ProductCount
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `over` you can do the same `group by` work in `aggregate functions`.

```
SELECT  
    DISTINCT Product_Category.id AS Category_ID,
    Product_Category.name AS Category_Name,
    Product_Category.parent_id AS Category_Parent,
    COUNT(Product.id) OVER (partition  BY Product_Category.id) AS ProductCount
FROM Product JOIN Product_Category ON Product.category_id = Product_Category.id
```

result in mysql : [https://dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8decdb876be2f903c35cfbbda312648d)

Answer (score 0):

So, I found the solution to the problem.

```
    SELECT
    X.id,
    X.category,
    X.parent,
    X.status,
    Y.product_count
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        c.id AS id,
        c.name AS Category,
        p.name AS Parent,
        c.status AS
    STATUS
FROM
    product_category c
LEFT JOIN product_category p ON
    c.parent_id = p.id
) X
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT
        c.id,
        COUNT(p.id) AS product_count
    FROM
        product_category c
    LEFT JOIN product p ON
        c.id = p.category_id
    GROUP BY
        p.category_id
) AS Y
ON
    X.id = Y.id
```